Validate headers in graphql + spring boot application
I created a spring boot application with graphql.I need to add spring security for authentication and authorization. My requirement is as below.
I need to validate headers, for example validate userId for incomming requests. When signIn or signUp mutations are called, there is no userId to be validated in headers. I need to permit only those signIn/signUp mutations without validating userIds in their headers.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> {
                registry.requestMatchers("/signIn", "/signUp").permitAll(); // Permit signIn, and signUp
                registry.anyRequest().authenticated(); // All other requests require authentication
            })
            .build();
    }
}

This type of filteration cannot afford here because there is only a single endpoint http://localhost:8080/graphql. How can I handle this scenario.
If it is not a good approach what are the best practices of doing this authentication & authorization part in spring boot + graphql application?
Thanks.

Doing what authentication? What do you want to protect? Certain queries? results? It is unclear.

I need to protect all the queries and mutations other than signin and signup mutations. signin and signup mutations can be accessed by any user. but all other queries/mutations should be accessible to the users who are already authenticated.

Should signin and signup even be part of the GraphQL endpoint? That being said if you want to protect the actual content you would need to write your own AuthorizationManager which checks the actual content of the request.
